# Extract Parameter from Url

Tags: c#, winforms, url

I have a winform application, and I would like to parse a string that represent an URL to extract some parameters.

a sample of the URL is this:

> http://www.mysite.com/itm/Sector-Watch/271443634510?pt=Orologi_da_Polso&hash=item3f334d294e

the parameter I would like to extract is `271443634510` (that is, the last part of the path before the query string).

Any idea ho how this can be done?

Comment: That is not a parameter, it is part of the [path](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Uri.Segments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.uri.segments), which splits up the stuff after your domain into an array that includes, for your example:

- /
- itm/
- Sector-Watch/
- 271443634510

So all you need to get is the item at index 3. Working example:

```
    string url = "http://www.mysite.com/itm/Sector-Watch/271443634510?pt=Orologi_da_Polso&hash=item3f334d294e";
    Uri uri = new Uri(url);
    var whatYouWant = uri.Segments[3];
```

Comment: You probably want to use `Segments.Last()` or `LastOrDefault` instead of hard-coding the index.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
string url = "http://www.mysite.com/itm/Sector-Watch/271443634510?pt=Orologi_da_Polso&hash=item3f334d294e";
string parameter = Regex.Match(url,"\d+(?=\?)|(?!/)\d+$").Value;
```

Comment: This doesn't work if there's no query string in the url.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `Split` function (tested and verified):

```
string MyUrl="http://www.mysite.com/itm/Sector-Watch/271443634510?pt=Orologi_da_Polso&hash=item3f334d294e";
string str=MyUrl.Split('/').Last().Split('?').First();
```